# Trouble moving files from folder to folder python

Tags: python, copy, shutil

I am having trouble moving files from one folder to another. I have written this simple code:

```
import os
import shutil

movePath = "C:\\Users\\BWhitehouse\\Documents\\GVRD\\MonthlySummary_03\\SCADA"


destPath = "I:\\eng\\GVRD\\Rain_Gauges\\MonthlyDownloads\\2014-03"

for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(movePath):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.xls'):
            shutil.copy(file, destPath)
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "C:\Python34\test.py", line 12, in <module> shutil.copy(file, destPath)   
File "C:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 228, in copy copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)   
File "C:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 107, in copyfile with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'BU07-201403.xls'
```

If anyone could help me out that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `os.path.join(dirpath,file)`

Answer (score 3):

The `file` variable is just the name, to get the full path add it to the `dirpath` variable:

```
shutil.copy( os.path.join(dirpath, file), destPath )
```

Comment: N.B. to OP: canonically you iterate through `os.walk` with `for root, dirs, files`. What's a `dirpath`? Future coders will thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you have full access to these folders? First check it out.
2. Start Python as Administrator by right-clicking, when you try to start the script.

I had the same problem. I solved the problem in this way.